# boost::log 1.66.0. Argument for set_filter from boost's tutorial is wrong

Tags: logging, boost, boost-log

I'm going thru boost::log library tutorial using Boost 1.66.0 and VS 2017.
Get the problem in the very beginning:

```
void init()  
{ 
  logging::core::get()->set_filter
  (
    logging::trivial::severity >= logging::trivial::info
  );
}
```

Error:
No operator ">=" matches these operands ...
It looks legitimate - First operand is a structure with no any comparison operators defined(including public base class. Did I miss some free functions?). Second operand is enum.
My question is how it is worked before?

Comment: Maybe headers that define `operator>=` should be included separately?

Comment: I suspect this will be the first of many problems with Boost logging. It's not a great library - it's over complicated not very user friendly. I'd recommend either looking for a different logging library or writing your own. Ultimately you'll end up doing one of these...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example code is not wrong and you can test that it compiles and runs, see `libs/log/example/doc/tutorial_trivial_flt.cpp` for the full code.

The first argument in the filter expression is a keyword and also a Boost.Phoenix terminal. It makes the filter expression build a Boost.Phoenix function object instead of evaluating the comparison immediately. The comparison operator is thus taken from Boost.Phoenix (`boost/phoenix/operator/comparison.hpp`, which is included through `boost/phoenix/operator.hpp` by `boost/log/expressions.hpp`).

Comment: Andrey, your library is good. What happens is VS 2017 editor showing the problem, but the code compiling and linking just fine. Thank you.

Comment: Code editors may have a hard time parsing through macros and templates involved in Boost.Phoenix and Boost.Proto, which Boost.Phoenix is built atop of. Unfortunately, I can't do much about that. Some IDEs are more clever (typically, those using Clang/LLVM to maintain internal code model, like QtCreator, for example).